# C++, переопределение уровня доступа метода

Tags: c++, классы, override

Подскажите, пожалуйста, будет ли неопределенное поведение в следующей ситуации:

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
  virtual void universal() final
  {
    concrete();
  }
protected:
  virtual void concrete() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
  void concrete() override
  {
    // ...
  }
};

int main()
{
  unique_ptr<Base> base = make_unique<Derived>();

  base->universal();

  return 0;
}
```

Меня смущает то, что метод `concrete()` переопределяется как `private`. Однако, в унаследованном методе `universal()` в базовом классе он виден как `protected`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вследствии наследования,  класс  `Derived` будет иметь функцию_член  `universal`  базового класса, которая свою очередь вызывает функцию_член `concrete`. Для  обьектов класса  `Derived` будет вызываться своя версия concrete, независимо от спецификатора доступа. Если она закрытая, то закрытая для клиентов, но члены класса (в данном случаи universal) и его друзья могут спокойно вызвать ее. Так что нет повода для сомнений в коде:

```
unique_ptr<Base> base = make_unique<Derived>();
base->universal();
```

Для обьекта класса  `Derived`, адрес которого хранит умный указатель, будет вызвана:

```
`Base::universal()`, а она будет вызывать `Derived::concrete`.
```

Защищенность метода базового класса позволяет пользоваться ею своим членам, друзьям и наследникам и закрыт для клиентов. В данном примере это чистая виртуальная функция, и так как она определяется в производных классах, то спецификатор доступа для данного примера значения  не имеет.

Answer (score 1):

В С++ не имеет никакого значения с каким уровнем доступа вы переопределяете виртуальную функцию. Функцию с любым уровнем доступа в базовом классе можно переопределять с любым уровнем доступа в классе-наследнике. Это корректно, поведение определено и никак не влияет на работу виртуальных вызовов.